# How does browser choose media type to filter CSS links?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, media

A page on my site has a link to a stylesheet for media="print".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Most browsers correctly ignore this link when rendering for a screen, but IE7 includes the file and processes the style rules, rendering the page inappropriately for a screen display.

How does IE (and how do other browsers) recognize what the intended display is?  Is there an HTML header (or absence of) that guides them?  Can this be correctly with Javascript?

Comment: Do you have a stylesheet with a `media="screen"` attribute on the page?

Comment: IE 6-8, Gecko-based browsers (eg. Firefox), Safari, Chrome, and Opera do support css media types.

Comment: Didn't you mean that IE 6-8 do not support CSS media types, but Gecko browsers do?  See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/more_about_medi.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@import` [at-rule](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-import) instead to include the file only for print and bypass IE7:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@import "print.css";
</style>
```

If that does not work, try the other alternatives on the [media test page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/media.html)